Woocommerce: how to quickly and correctly get the total amount of sales for each taxonomy?
The site has a taxonomy: my_taxonomy. I need to get the total amount of sales for each custom product taxonomy, list for level 1 and for level 2, I mean it:
Level0
-level1 <-- this 
--level2 <-- this
---level3
--level2 <-- this
-level1 <-- this
--level2 <-- this
---level3
---level3
I did it like this:
function handle_csv_export()
{

  if (! wp_verify_nonce($_POST['_wpnonce'], 'generate-csv')) {
    return;
  }

  $orders = wc_get_orders(array(
    'limit' => -1,
    'status' => array('completed', 'processing', 'on-hold')
  ));

  $levels1 = $levels2 = array();
  foreach (get_terms('my_taxonomy', array('hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0)) as $parent_term) {
    foreach (get_terms('my_taxonomy', array('hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => $parent_term->term_id)) as $child_term) {
      $levels1[] = array("value" => $child_term->term_id, "label" => $child_term->name); //get level1
      foreach (get_terms('my_taxonomy', array('hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => $child_term->term_id)) as $third_term) {
        $levels2[] = array("value" => $third_term->term_id, "label" => $third_term->name); //get level2
      }
    }
  }


  $level1_amount_result = $level2_amount_result = array();

  foreach ($orders as $order) {
    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ($items as $item) {
      $product_id = $item->get_product_id();

      foreach ($levels1 as $level1) {
        if (has_term($level1['value'], 'my_taxonomy', $product_id)) {
          $level1_amount_result[$level1['label']] += $item->get_total(); //adding up the price for each taxonomy
        }
      }
      foreach ($levels2 as $level2) {
        if (has_term($level2['value'], 'my_taxonomy', $product_id)) {
          $level2_amount_result[$level2['label']] += $item->get_total();
        }
      }
    }

  }

  // add to csv
  $filetime = time();

  $list = array(
    array("levels1"),
  );

  foreach ($level1_amount_result as $level1_name => $level1_amount) {
    array_push($list, array($level1_name, $level1_amount . '$'));
  }

  array_push($list, array("levels2"));

  foreach ($level2_amount_result as $level2_name => $level2_amount) {
    array_push($list, array($level2_name, $level2_amount . '$'));
  }

  $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
  $file_path = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/myorders/myorders' . $filetime . '.csv';
  $folder_path = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/myorders';
  if (!file_exists($folder_path)) {
    mkdir($folder_path, 0777);
  }
  $files = glob($folder_path . '/*');

  foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (is_file($file)) {
      unlink($file);
    }
  }

  header('Content-Type: text/csv');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');

  $file = fopen($file_path, "w");

  foreach ($list as $line) {
    fputcsv($file, $line);
  }
  readfile($file_path);
  fclose($file);
  exit;
}

https://prnt.sc/BEvAcv34kgqZ
It seems to work with a small number of orders, but the site has many values ​​in the taxonomy and many orders, the code takes a long time to execute and the site crashes. How can I speed up this process? Thanks.

This should have been planned from the start: You should have set or update those amounts for each taxonomy term as custom term metadata, each time an order get the processing status for example, you can set/update the amount by order item (product)… Also, instead of making multiple term queries for your custom taxonomy, make it just once and sort the terms by parent with PHP in a unique multidimensional array (including the amount from your custom term metadata)… Then, from this multidimensional array, you can make your CSV export. Don't forget that WooCommerce orders increase each day…

ok, Ill try to change, thx
